# Query a JSON object with Python based on two or more filters on different levels

Tags: python, json

I am a bit lost when trying to query a json object which looks like the following. I want to query by  the sub key `"type": "header1"` and the sub sub key `"type": "simpletext"`. And i want to receive all results where i can loop through.

This is the initial raw json:

```
{
  "obj": "typed",
  "results": [
      {
        "obj": "blocktext",
        "type": "header1",
        "header1": {
          "rich_text": [
            {
              "type": "simpletxt",
              "txt": "About me"
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "obj": "blocktext",
        "type": "header1",
        "header1": {
          "rich_text": [
            {
              "type": "simpletxt",
              "txt": "Imprint"
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "obj": "blocktext",
        "type": "header1",
        "header1": {
          "rich_text": [
            {
              "type": "simpletxt",
              "txt": "About me"
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "obj": "blocktext",
        "type": "code",
        "code": {
          "rich_text": [
            {
              "type": "javascript",
              "txt": "ABCDEFG"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
}
```

I am trying to do this with Python in Google Colabs but i have absolutely no clue how two query a json object by two or more parameters and on different levels.

Comment: The first thing that sticks out: all your objects have the `type` key twice. That's going to be a problem since Python will drop the earlier one on parsing.

Comment: Oh oh, you are totally right, that was a mistake by me during editing/reducing the json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your json is in a variable called `jstr`, you can convert to a dict using [`json.loads`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads), then use [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) to select the sub-dictionaries in `results` that have `'type' == 'header1'` and then the sub-type variable equal to `'simpletxt'`:

```py
dd = json.loads(jstr)
res = list(filter(lambda r:r['type'] == 'header1' and r['header1']['rich_text'][0]['type'] == 'simpletxt', dd['results']))
```

Output:

```
[
    {
        "obj": "blocktext",
        "type": "header1",
        "header1": {
            "rich_text": [
                {
                    "type": "simpletxt",
                    "txt": "About me"
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "obj": "blocktext",
        "type": "header1",
        "header1": {
            "rich_text": [
                {
                    "type": "simpletxt",
                    "txt": "Imprint"
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "obj": "blocktext",
        "type": "header1",
        "header1": {
            "rich_text": [
                {
                    "type": "simpletxt",
                    "txt": "About me"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

Note the above assumes (as in your sample data) that the `rich_text` list only contains one item. If it can contain many, you will need to change the filter to check that [`all`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) or [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) (dependent on your needs) of the sub-type variables are `'simpletxt'`. For example:

```py
# any
res = list(filter(lambda r:r['type'] == 'header1' and any(rt['type'] == 'simpletxt' for rt in r['header1']['rich_text']), dd['results']))
# all
res = list(filter(lambda r:r['type'] == 'header1' and all(rt['type'] == 'simpletxt' for rt in r['header1']['rich_text']), dd['results']))
```

For your sample data, both of these return the same results as there is only one value in the `rich_text` list.